# Nothing happens when I run an example Selenium python script

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to run an example Selenium Python script (https://github.com/dakotasmith/page-object-examples) which is supposed to show the Page Object Model. His instructions to run are on the page, README.md

I can run example 1. The browser opens and selenium goes through its asserts. But nothing happens when I run Example 2 (https://i.stack.imgur.com/GoHgg.jpg).

When I run example 3, I get a no connection error (https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSl9r.jpg).

I have started the webserver with `python -m http.server 9090` since I am running Python 3.

**Why does nothing happen with example_02.py and what is with the connection error with example_03.py?**

Comment: In README.md, it shows you need to use `py.test scripts/example_02.py` to run example 2 as it is a test case. In example 3, admittedly  it is strange. The code shows that you have to setup a server located at localhost:4444.

Comment: Oops! I see: I need to install a Python module called pytest. For example 3, is it just incomplete? I don't understand what he means by "standalone script".

Comment: Maybe. standalone script means it can run without any other dependencies. But it seems not true.

Comment: I tried running something called a remote Webdriver, but running this in my Python/Selenium folder `java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.5.0.jar`. But that didn't work.

Comment: I also tried changing this code in example_02.py. `from pago.driver import WebDriver
desired_capabilities = {'browserName': 'chrome'}
#command_executor = "http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub"
command_executor = "http://0.0.0.0:9090/"`

Comment: This was the error I was getting after running `python scripts/example_03.py` There's also a screenshot of the local web server running. https://imgur.com/a/BO5cO

Comment: Read README.md carefully, you need to run `python -m http.server 9090` in `sites` dir. "Just switch to the sites dir and run the following command"

Comment: I am running that web server. Check second screenshot here: https://imgur.com/a/BO5cO. From some research `from pago.errors import ExpectedElementError
from pago.driver import WebDriver
desired_capabilities = {'browserName': 'chrome'}
command_executor = "http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub"` seems to be code to use something called a "remote webdriver". Example 01 does not have this code and so runs fine.

Comment: yes you are running that web server, but in a wrong directory. You do have to run it in `sites` directory.

Comment: UGH. THANKS!! I was running the web server in the wrong directory. Also, I needed to run that remote webdriver (java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.5.0.jar)

Comment: Dude example2 doesnt work because, there is no executing code (like a main method). A class is created, no object is created. But Im getting the same error for example3.

Comment: Anyone know why the developer has the remote webdriver run for Example 2 and 3? I'm guessing he doesn't like running scripts locally?

Comment: @TheChetan. I got example3 to work. I ran the web server in the Site directory and ran the remote webdriver (java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.5.0.jar) in my Selenium folder.

Comment: @StacyM you may check this project https://github.com/gunesmes/page-object-python-selenium. It test amazon web site so you change it something else. Just clone it and run `python testPages.py`

Comment: @Mesut GUNES, I've seen this one before! Wow thanks for responding. Is there anything else you would add to your framework? I was looking at the example in this post because it adds a wait_for_avaialble method for locators. Also, can you suggest what order you would create a new framework for a new site? Is it base.py, locators.py, pages.py, testcases, testpages then users.py?

Comment: @StacyM I will update waiting methods and modularise it. The problem with the project you are asking, there are some parts didn't implemented so you need to do that parts. Best you can do is to ask your questions to the developer on the github page.